# Right Click on Open Space with scripts in nautilus 13.04

Tags: 13.04, scripts, nautilus-script

In 12.04, I was able to create a script in the ~.gnome2/nautilus-scripts folder and it was available when I 'right click'.

I have a script that creates a folder structure for new customers:

```
mkdir Documents
mkdir Documents/Customer
mkdir Documents/Lics
mkdir Documents/%MyCompanyName%
mkdir Documents/%MyCompanyName%/Quotes
mkdir Documents/Mfg
mkdir Documents/Deliverable
mkdir Documents/Validations
mkdir Configs
mkdir Configs/Sites
mkdir Configs/worksheets
mkdir Configs/Backups
mkdir Configs/Logs
mkdir Caps
mkdir Diagrams
mkdir Diagrams/Screenshots
mkdir Diagrams/Visio
mkdir Scripts
```

I would create a folder under a "clients" folder (customerA) containing the project I was working on that day (or week).  I would then open the folder, right-click on the open space and choose the scripts, 'mktree' script.  It would populate each customer file with all the necessary folders.

I can no longer do this in 13.04.  Well, maybe I can but have not figured it out.  I saw some threads about scripts on a file or folder but not white space.

This not only keeps me organized but also is easy to run a rsync to backup "certain" customer data to our server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It has been reported as a bug... no walk arround so far (let me know if you find one). 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1179744

But you can click on the client's folder instead and pass it as an argument to the script using nautilus-scripts variables and modify your script to create the subfolders on it.Whenever a script is called, Nautilus automatically sets a handful of variables that can be used in your scripts.

NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS - newline-delimited paths for selected files (only if local)

NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS - newline-delimited URIs for selected files

NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI - current location

NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_WINDOW_GEOMETRY - position and size of current window